# How to call async methods

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, task-parallel-library

Imagine there is a method

```
async static System.Threading.Tasks.Task Do()
{
    //do sth
    await Task.Delay(10000);
}
```

now , when I call the method with

```
Do();
```

Does it make a new thread ? or I have to create a thread as below

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Do());
```

Comment: You have to use the await keyword, just like you did with Task.Delay. Although the second method would work too, but then you wouldn't need the async modifier.

Comment: This article might be helpful  http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Do` doesn't create a thread.

The part before the await runs on the calling thread and there's no thread at all during the delay. `Task.Delay` uses a timer internally which doesn't hold up a thread throughout the operation.

When the delay completes a thread from the ThreadPool is used to continue executing the method.

About `Task.Factory.StartNew`, why would you want to create a thread? If you need to offload a CPU intensive method to the thread pool then it's fine (although `Task.Run` is preferable) but if you don't then simply call `Do` and await the result:

```
await Do();
```

If you insist on creating a new thread for `Do` you need to use `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`:

```
Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Do(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

But since `Do` is an async method that releases the thread when it reaches the first await this doesn't make any sense as I've explained on my blog: [LongRunning Is Useless For Task.Run With async-await](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/)

Comment: so , if I call it like System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Do()); , a new thread would be created ? if no, what is the solution to create a new thread before await ?

Comment: `StartNew` doesn't create a thread. It offloads to the `ThreadPool`. If you want to create a new thread you need to pass `TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning`  but since your method is asynchronous that is pointless. You can read about it on my blog: [LongRunning Is Useless For Task.Run With async-await](http://blog.i3arnon.com/2015/07/02/task-run-long-running/)

Comment: I want to have some threads that every thread does something different .

Answer (score -1):

All my case is this :

```
 public void Start(Action action)
    {
        Token = CancellationToken.None;
        IsRunning = true;

       Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Do(action), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
    }

    async Task Do(Action action)
    {
        while (IsRunning)
        {
            action();

            await Task.Delay(Interval, Token);

        }
    }
```

then I call Start() with five different actions with different intervals. 
Is this Correct to use ?

Comment: As I stated in my answer, yes it is. Even though the `LongRunning` is redundant.

Comment: you said  "But since Do is an async method that releases the thread when it reaches the first await"  . does it release the thread when it reaches the first await here ? If so , How can I make it a thread which is alive until app runs?

Comment: You can't. The whole point of an async method is that the thread is released when it's not needed. That's not a drawback. It's a good thing.

Comment: but I want a thread that checks a queue , if there is any item in it, then dequeue and do some operations .it should be running all the time.

Comment: what about using a Thread.Sleep(Interval); instead of await Task.Delay(Interval, Token); ? or maybe I shouldn't use Task in my scenario ?

Comment: Then you would indeed have a thread all the time. But it would be sleeping and doing nothing throughout `Thread.Sleep`. `Task.Delay` is better, when it completes the rest will run on the `ThreadPool`.

Comment: when I delete await , a warning will be shown , "This async method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously. Consider using the 'await' operator to await non-blocking API calls, or 'await Task.Run(...)' to do CPU-bound work on a background thread." Is it better to use "await Task.Run" in my case ?